# apache configuration for cohosting mod_python and php based apps

Tags: apache-2.2, php, django, mod-python

I have django+python+apache2+mod_python installed hosted and working on ubuntu server/ linode VPS. php5 is installed and configured. We don't have a domain name as in example.com. Just IP address. So my apache .conf file looks like this

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost DocumentRoot /var/www

```
<Location "/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
        PythonOption django.root /mysite
        PythonPath "['/var/www/djangoprojects',] + sys.path"
        PythonDebug On
</Location>
```

I want to install vtiger so if I change my .conf file like say this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vtigercrm/
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.access_log combined
<Directory /var/www/vtigercrm>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

This way vtiger the php based app works fine and ofcourse django app is not accessible. How do I make both co-exist in one file. i cannot use virtual host/subdomains. I can do with a diff port no thou.

Any clue guys ?

Regards Ankur Gupta

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup. The root is handled by mod_python which is running an instance of trac and /docs is handled by dokuwiki which uses php.

The only way to make this work was to use a `LocationMatch` directive that I had to negate because trac uses quite a numer of pseudo-directories:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!docs)">
    SetHandler mod_python
</LocationMatch>
```